# How to do autocomplete using values from the database in MVC 5?

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

At the moment, I have the following code:

**main.js:**

```
$(function () {
    var keys = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

    $("#keywords-manual").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: keys
    });
});
```

**Test.cshtml:**

```
@model App.Models.Service
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAndShare", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new request.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ServiceType, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ServiceType, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "keywords-manual" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit!" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The point is that currently I have just provided 4 constant values to the autocomplete. But then I created a database and a table named "services", which comes from my model named Service. I have already provided a few rows to the table with values. I have a field in my table called ServiceType, and I want the autocomplete to take the values of that column as a source. Please note that I have hosted my database in Azure and it is MySQL, though, I think it doesn't matter here. Can you tell me how can I take as a source the values of ServiceType column that is located inside my services table?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell by your question, it should look something like this:

```
$("#keywords-manual").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetServiceTypes",
            data: "{ 'keywords': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.value,
                        value: item.value,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                }))
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

And the controller,

```
YourContext db = new YourContext();
public JsonResult GetServiceTypes() {
    db.ServiceType.Where(s => keywords == null || s.Name.ToLower()
        .Contains(keywords.ToLower()))
        .Select(x => new { id = x.ServiceTypeID, value = x.ServiceTypeName }).Take(5).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Apologies for any typos, but that should be the jist of it. If you need to be searching for more than one keyword, in the controller method, split the value from 'keywords-manual' into a string array, then use a foreach loop or similar approach to match each value, adding matches to a total list each time.

** I say string array, that's pretty oldschool, split it into a list :)